# routing the page after running scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am getting below error when I am trying to route the about page which I did with `rails g scaffold about`.

> undefined local variable or method `map' for main:Object Did you mean? tap

This is what I have in the `routes.rb` file.

```
map.about '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about'
```

Comment: Which rails version you are using?

Comment: I am using `rails 4`

Comment: Can you post your complete routes file?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`get '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about'`

or

`post '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about'`

or

`match '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about', via: [:get, :post]`

Comment: none of them working! 

`get '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about'` when I use this, I get this
 `undefined method get for main:Object Did you mean? gets gem`

Comment: do u have `Rails.application.routes.draw do` `end` in ur route

Comment: I have generated this error by commenting `Rails.application.routes.draw do`

`end` lines in the config/route.rb

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails g scaffold about` this command will generate multiple files, include model, views, and will write `resource :abouts` to the `routes.rb` file.

The routes syntax is not right.
`map.about '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about'`

if you just want to create a about page, url set as `/about`

1. create a controller named `abouts_controller.rb`, in the `/app/controllers` folder
2. create a action `def index; end` in `abouts_controller.rb`
3. create a view file named `abouts.html.erb` in the folder `app/views/abouts`.(you will creat the folder)
4. write routes to `routes.rb`

`get :about, :controller => :abouts, :action => :index`

or

`get '/about' to: "abouts#index"`

or

`match '/about', :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'about'`

Comment: Can you post your complete routes file?

Comment: It's a spree app just to let you know. Missed it to put there. Does that make any difference?